# My Google Voice services keeps getting stuck on “restarting”

Tags: google-voice, services

The "UpdateService" for Google Voice constantly keeps getting stuck on "restarting" and therefore I miss out on receiving SMS messages from Google Voice. I've already been trimming down on some unnecessary services and it doesn't seem like it has helped a whole lot. Any other suggestions or thoughts about this problem?

I'm currently running CM6, but it happened before on stock too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen this particular issue before, but Kevin Purdy's "Holy Trinity" of steps to take with apps that just aren't working properly is:

From Settings | Applications | Manage applications | <application>

- Force stop

if that doesn't help

- Clear cache

if that doesn't help

- Clear data

and if that still doesn't help, try the nuclear option:

- uninstall and re-install